# Target specific row in multi-line text?

Tags: css, text, target, multiline

The original problem is that i need to make a font less italic than the italic font, but still more italic than normal. There is only those two to choose between, but i need something in between, and as far as i know there is no other way to manually set the skew of a font using the font-style property.

Then i came to think of the `CSS3` transform property. It allows you to skew any element. The plan is to use that, and for browsers that don't support it, i'll fall back to normal italic which doesn't look as good. The only problem is, since the entire element is skewed, the text looks sort of indented.

Take a look at this pic, you'll see what i mean:

[image: picture]

As you can see, the transform make it look more indented on every line.

The solution to that would be to target specific lines and use a negative margin (or text indent) to counter the indent-effect caused by the transform property.

So, is it possible to target specific lines of text in a multi-line text segment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with CSS, nor with javascript.
There's no character to mark the endline, since words are inline element.

Although **I'd need to see the code** on how you did your skewing, I believe you did it on the whole block. So maybe you could break it down to the text instead.

If you can't apply your effect to inline element, you could try to put your text in small floating block elements.

#### Edit :

[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qeDeK/). It's an extreme case with a lot more skewing. As you can see, it's the whole block (the `p`) that is skewed.

As I wrote, you could break it down with a js function to small, floating block elements.  [I made a working example too](http://jsfiddle.net/qeDeK/1/). It probably should be optimized as it might get heavy on processing. And you could still not have any special markup for your CMS.

Comment: Actually, i might be able to do it with javascript? I would preferably avoid it if possible though. The HTML is just a simple <p> tag with text inside it. I can't wrap each line because it has to be editable through a CMS, and to wrap each line with a tag would be too much hassle for them, especially since they don't know when the line will break until viewing it in the browser. The CSS is just a simple transform copied from css3please.com (scroll down and look at the .matrix box).

Comment: I've edited my answer with more details and a possible solutions for you.

Comment: Yes, i know the entire block is skewed, but if i could select specific lines, i would be able to manually set the text indent for the specified line. Your solution however, is much better! I don't need do do any specific styling, it will be applied to everything. I don't think there is a better solution than this, so i'm going to use your code. Thanks!